# Node.js ECONNRESET error when running on azure

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have a node express application which runs fine locally. But when running on azure I am seeing periodic errors which I cant figure out.

I have installed longjohn to get more details on the issue. The error is:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
at exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:544:26)
---------------------------------------------
at fireErrorCallbacks (net.js:444:15)
at TLSSocket.Socket._destroy (net.js:480:3)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:544:17)
```

This seems to happen once every minute or so. Could anyone shine any light on this?

I also have redis installed but am listening for any events for loss of connection or error which do not fire, so I am assuming it is something to do with express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do when the error occurs?

I had a similar problem with Node on Azure. The application itself ran nicely on Azure, but every now and then the connection to the database would take 40+ seconds. After investigating with Azure on this, we found out that there is a idle-connection system in Azure, where connections with no activity after x seconds are put into this pool of idle connections (Think of it like a garbage collector); The only workaround as concluded by us and the Azure specialist team was to add a periodic "ping" to the connection, to keep it active. So basically we started pinging the database once every 20 sec or so (for each connection to it)

Not sure if it solves your problem, but still relevant for your node on Azure setting, so hope it helps either way!

Comment: I am connecting to a documentDB database so this may be a similar error. Currently I am just catching the error with process.on('uncaughtException'...  which is still not ideal but stops the app from crashing. Ill look into the db connection further, thanks.

Comment: Great! I know the pain of this problem, struggled over 2 weeks before resolving it :)

Comment: the applications on Azure Web apps will sleep after idle time, to save the payload. You can enable the setting `Always On`, then the Azure infrastructure will ping your service at intervals to keep your application awake.

Comment: @wazzaday which documentDB database were you using. I am also facing the same issue with couchDB